# Unexpected behaviour of self implemented priority queue using min heap

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue, min-heap

I implemented a priority queue using a min heap in c++;
here I use zero based indexing in the vector used;
so for example the left and right nodes of index 5 would be (2 * 5 + 1) and (2 * 5 + 2);
I use recursive functions like swim and sink (typical);

here's the c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class t>
class priorityqueue
{
private:
    vector<t> vec;

    inline static void swap(t *x, t *y)
    {
        t temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    }

    inline static size_t left(size_t i) { return (i << 1) + 1; }

    inline static size_t right(size_t i) { return (i << 1) + 2; }

    inline static size_t up(size_t i) { return (i - 1) >> 1; }

    inline bool validindex(size_t i) { return i < vec.size(); }

    inline void swim(size_t i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            return;
        size_t up_ = up(i);
        if (vec[i] < vec[up_])
        {
            swap(&vec[i], &vec[up_]);
            swim(up_);
        }
    }

    inline void sink(size_t i)
    {
        size_t left_ = left(i), right_ = right(i);
        if (!validindex(left_))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!validindex(right_))
        {
            if (vec[i] > vec[left_])
            {
                swap(&vec[i], &vec[left_]);
                sink(left_);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (vec[i] < vec[left_])
        {
            if (vec[i] < vec[right_])
            {
                return;
            }
            swap(&vec[i], &vec[right_]);
            sink(right_);
        }
        else
        {
            if (vec[i] < vec[right_])
            {
                swap(&vec[i], &vec[left_]);
                sink(left_);
            }
            else
            {
                if (vec[left_] < vec[right_])
                {
                    swap(&vec[i], &vec[left_]);
                    sink(left_);
                }
                else
                {
                    swap(&vec[i], &vec[right_]);
                    sink(right_);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public:
    size_t size() { return vec.size(); }

    bool empty() { return size() == 0; }

    void push(t elem)
    {
        vec.push_back(elem);
        swim(vec.size() - 1);
    }

    t peek()
    {
        return vec[0];
    }

    t pop()
    {
        t elem = vec[0];
        t last = vec[vec.size() - 1];
        swap(&last, &elem);
        vec.pop_back();
        sink(0);
        return elem;
    }
};

int main()
{
    priorityqueue<int> pq;
    pq.push(3);
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(4);
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(5);
    pq.push(9);
    pq.push(2);
    pq.push(6);
    pq.push(5);
    pq.push(3);
    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        cout << pq.pop() << " ";
    }
}
```

the result it gives is :

```
(base) miglanigursimar@Miglanis-MacBook-Pro priorityqueue % ./a.out 
5 5 6 4 9 3 3 2 1 1 %
```

whereas it should print the first ten digits of pi in ascending order.

Comment: 1) Why did you feel the need of reimplementing `swap` using pointers? 2) Please explain what happens in `pop`, in particular what `swap(&last, &elem);` is doing.

Comment: Your `sink` code has a lot of extraneous stuff and looks fairly buggy.  It should contain only two comparisons -- one `vec[i] < vec[left]` and one `vec[i] < vec[right]` (along with the two validindex checks -- so only 4 `if`s total in the function)

Comment: The main issue is indeed that `swap(&last, &elem)`: it has no effect on the vector. Will work better if instead you do `swap(&vec[vec.size() - 1], &vec[0]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big issue is in the `pop` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class t>
class priorityqueue
{
private:
    vector<t> vec;

    inline static void swap(t *x, t *y)   // Why? Use std::swap instead.
    {
        t temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    }

// [...]
  
    t pop()
    {
        t elem = vec[0];
        t last = vec[vec.size() - 1];
        swap(&last, &elem);             // <---------
        vec.pop_back();
        sink(0);
        return elem;
    }
};
// [...]
```

There, `last` and `elem` are **local copies** of the two elements of the vector, swapping them doesn't change the original ones.

The OP should either declare those as **references** or copy the first and then directly swap the elements of the vector.